# Common words used over thousands of row in MySQL Database using PHP (or query)

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a MySQL database that has large amount of records. For each record there is a field of text called "Comment" and I've put 3 examples below:

- "Very fast payment, thank you. "
- "love the thank you"
- "Fast delivery thank u "

My question is this:

**How do I interrogate each record look at the contents of the "Comment" field and then work out what the top 20 words used are?**

For example using the 3 comments above the words

- "thank" appears 3 times,
- "Fast" 2 times
- And the rest of the words used are only used once.

I am guessing that I'll need to use PHP to work through each record, explode out using a " " (space), remove characters like commas & full stops, then store the results and then count those.

But I am really not sure on the best approach and not sure how to handle plurals such as "thanks" & "thank". Hence the question :)

Matt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because they are all in the one column you can't really do much SQL filtering here.

If the data set isn't too huge (i.e. php running out of memory huge) then you should be able to read it into php and process it.

You can use `explode` to split on spaces and work with the data as a huge array. And you can use preg_match function to do string compare operations, see: https://www.php.net/preg_match - you should spend some time investigating regular expressions.

It would be easier to use the SQL `like` function in the where clause if you were looking for something specific like SELECT COUNT(comment) where comment like '%thank%'` but you would have to do that manually.

Also, you may want to consider dumping it out to a file and using unix-based commands like `wc` which can help you with what you are after. You can also use PHP to interact with these commands if you are in a unix-like environment.

Short of writing the code there isn't much more I can tell you.

Comment: Yea the database is huge +1M records. Basically not one single approach is going to work. Now thinking call the rows in batches of 10,000, then in batches of 1,000 explode out the contents, add to an array counting as we go, serialize them, store them, do the next batch and repeat.

Then as you suggest use the LIKE query to grab a count of the variations once I've got a very good idea of the common words used.

Comment: ini_set("memory_limit", 2000M); might help here too. You can use LIMIT in mysql to do 10,000 at a time and write them to disk to slurp in. Unix is your friend for stuff like this :P

Answer (score 1):

Possible, perhaps. However, MySQL is not really good for this type of querying. If you did attempt this using MySQL is is likely to take a long time to actually complete and would not be practical if you wanted to run this type of query frequently.

I'd suggest you look into indexing your data using something that is specifically designed for these kind of queries. Some kind of Apache Lucene derivative would do nicely, for example you could use Elasticsearch. Here are the docs from ES that describe the kind of query you are looking to run: http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-facets-terms-facet.html

Unlike MySQL running these kind of queries on something like ES would execute very quickly as it is specifically designed for it.